# Facebook Graph API posts appear in user places, but not timeline

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm working on a site where users can post reviews of places, and then optionally share these review on Facebook. The FB auth is done during login, and the `publish_stream` permission is requested at that time.

When I submit the "User posted a review" event to Facebook (API endpoint: `/USERID/APPID:action`, with `place` and `review` POST params), it shows up in the Activity Log, and on the user Places map (the action includes a place), but not on the user timeline.

When I use my personal account – that's also the app developer account – the review is posted on my timeline. When I post through the app's Test User, the review fails to show up on the timeline.

Am I doing something obvious wrong, or is it how the Facebook API is supposed to work?

--

I can share more specific code if needed, but since the action is successfully posted to Facebook, just not the way I want, it appears I'm confused about the big picture logic, or something about the Facebook App configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the API in the correct way, since the activity is being posted to the Activity feed. However, these posts won't always appear in the user's timeline automatically (I think tere is a Facebook algorithm in play here that controls this). However, a user can manually add that activity to their timeline from the Activity Log and clicking on the Edit button.